# Disable console access?

Tags: 12.04, ssh, authentication, console

How do I disable console access to Ubuntu 12.04? I want to only allow login over SSH.

I have searched the web thoroughly but no clear answer was found.

EDIT: I'm talking about disabling physical console access.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for you is to install **Ubuntu server** which has no GUI and is used by connecting via SSH from a remote computer(this is the recommmended way)

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to know is how I can disable **physical** console access. I want to disable login from keyboard connected to machine, and only allow remote login by SSH.

Comment: @user252853 boot and remove the monitor.That's the only way I can come up with

Answer (score 0):

You can by using Pam module called `pam_listfile.so` which can help you securing your system by choosing some groups to login .

First create a file you specified a group just to login like root .

```
vi /etc/login.group.allowed
```

add the group name :

root ( you can specify just your user by creating a specific group for it )

save and close .

As i understand you want to deny login graphically so in lightdm .

Now open `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`

add the following ad the top of the file :

```
auth required pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=group sense=allow file=/etc/login.group.allowed
```

To explain more:

you specify the pam module to use which is pam_listfile.so

required means if the user is not in the group don't authenticate

Conclusion : you deny users to authenticate by login graphically , but they still can login by ssh .

**Be careful !**

I hope this answer satisfy your need .